# Converting a pandas dataframe into python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dataframe into dictionary which has columns in the following order

```
df.columns = Index([u'Symbol', u'Name', u'MarketCap', u'IPOyear', u'Sector', u'Industry'], dtype='object')
```

when I converted by using

```
df.to_dict(orient = 'list')
```

I got a dictionary with the keys in following order

```
dict1.keys() = ['Sector', 'Name', 'Symbol', 'MarketCap', 'IPOyear', 'Industry']
```

I want the order to be unchanged. anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Python dictionaries are not ordered, so you cannot do that.

Comment: But I have a need of loading that dictionary into MySQLdb table.

Comment: if you need order then you should convert to list

Comment: Do you need to iterated over your dict to load it to MySQLdb table?

Comment: Thank you. I am trying it now.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to do that, but I am getting an error @Akavall

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python@Akavall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which can *remember the order that keys were first inserted*:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
myDict = OrderedDict()

for col in df.columns:
    myDict[col] = df[col].tolist()
```